# How can developers effectively manage and resolve pull request issues on GitHub?

Tags: github

How can developers handle merge conflicts in GitHub when multiple users are working on the same file?
How can developers effectively manage and resolve pull request issues on GitHub?

I have not found related answers anywhere

Comment: Rebase the feature branch, resolve the conflicts locally, assess what version is correct, then force-push to github

Answer (score 0):

**For Handling Merge Conflicts Do This:**

If you prefer a clean commit history, use rebase:

```
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/main
```

If you prefer a merge commit, use merge:

```
git fetch origin
git merge origin/main
```

Now push changes to the branch using

```
git push origin <your-branch-name>
```

**For Managing Pull Request Issues Try This:**

To keep the commit history neat, if the pull request has numerous commits, try squashing them into one commit:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~<number of commits>
```

To keep the repository clean after the pull request has been merged, remove the feature branch:

```
git branch -d <your-branch-name>
git push origin --delete <your-branch-name>
```